# Update css class in real-time with websockets

Tags: php, jquery, html, sockets, websocket

Im facing a problem in my browser game, its a risk style game, so i have regions with colors after who owns it.

Each path line of this svg data is stored in the database with a unique id, and the class is created by "faction" and then the unique region ownership added after from 1-5 which dictates the owner.

When a region is captured, the region ownership changes, and if the page is refreshed, it will have the correct color, but this is obviously not gonna work with up to 200 regions changing all the time, the page would have to refresh constantly.

The class is here: [image]

And the regions look like this:
[image]

Just an addition, each region have a unique id, and each path line is looped out to the users like this: [image]

So question in short.

How do i update a class in real-time to all clients on the page?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: This is fairly simple. You need to attempt it and then include the code that you have tried.

Comment: https://blog.pusher.com/making-angular-js-realtime-with-pusher/ one of the results I'm including here after Googling "update in real-time with websockets". You can further your research from there.

Comment: Ah yes i did come across Pusher, but was unsure if it was the correct way to do this. So im gladly taking more suggestions to get me on the right path. So many solutions to one problem :), btw Pusher got pricing per connections, and for the connections im gonna get, this will cost me hundreds of $ per month. So that wont work.

Comment: I imagine they're all the same solution really. In pseudo code: `socket.on('message', function(message) {
  myElem.className = message.className;
});`

Comment: Presumably each of those paths has a unique ID?

Comment: Yes, each path have unique id which matches an id in my database. You can see how i loop out path lines [link](http://i.imgur.com/3dSXuUH.png)

Comment: I've not used it so can't recommend, but [phpws](https://github.com/Devristo/phpws) looks like it might do the server-side job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving Ajax use case as i don't have any idea how to use web sockets in php. however whole part should be quite simply translatable to web sockets.

Lets assume each path have one fraction.

So we create php file refresh.php.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(result)){
$array[$row['RegionId']] = 'Fraction'.$row['FractionId'] ;
}
echo json_decode($array);
```

Then in JS:

```
$.getJSON('refresh.php'/*path to refresh*/).done(function(data){
   $.each(data,function(index,value){
      $(index).attr('class',value);
   });
});
```

Obviously this scripts lacks few things, but it's good start.

Comment: Hi there Maciej. I already have the code finished for changing "ownership" class of the regions. Its simply the real-time updating to all other users connected to this page i need to see the update. But thanks for your time thou

Comment: Ah sorry, Yeah just wrap ajax in `setInterval` and repeat it every second for example. Web worker will be nicer solution, but I would highly recommend to use node for that, specially that response time is quite important here as it is game.

Comment: This will be to ressource intensive. There will be thousands of regions in 1 game, and there will be many games. So each refresh would take a lot of ressources.

I need to only update the region that have changed. I am investigating myself aswell thou, and maybe got a solution with normal websockets.

Comment: so you can send only those ones that changed. I wanted to show example how to use it only. It's not full solution, but is only supposed to show how to tackle problems like this. If you will use websockets you will still probably have to remember about fallback for ajax. By connecting it with other example you can do it work properly. You can also speed it up by not using jquery and preselecting dom elements and keeping it in the array or creating proper Object oriented Javascript.

Comment: I tried the Web socket path, and me and another programmer decided that it was to heavy for us, not enough knowledge for us to continue with it sadly. So we will use a version of your example instead, and then later when it becomes to heavy for the server, possibly move to web socket.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I would highly recommend node for this example. Especially if you know a little bit of javascript. I am not saying js is better than php, but for this case asynchronus language  is easier to deal with. Can I ask where did you took the svg map from? I always had problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/walkor/workerman. It's a socket framework for php.

Websocket example: Create websocket_server.php

```
<?php
require_once './Workerman/Autoloader.php';
use Workerman\Worker;
use Workerman\Lib\Timer;

// Listen 2347 port use websocket protocol
$websocket_worker = new Worker("Websocket://0.0.0.0:2347");

// Example create one process handle connections
$websocket_worker->count = 1;

// All websocket connections
$connections_array = array();
// RegionId
$region_id = 1;

// When connect
$websocket_worker->onConnect = function($connection)
{
    global $connections_array, $region_id;
    $connection->RegionId = $region_id++;
    $connections_array[$connection->RegionId] = $connection;
};

// When a message received from one client
$websocket_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $message)
{
    global $connections_array;
    foreach($connections_array as $conn)
    {
        $conn->send("region_id[{$connection->RegionId}] send a message:$message");
    }
};

// When connection closed
$websocket_worker->onClose = function($connection)
{
    global $connections_array;
    unset($connections_array[$connection->RegionId]);
};

// Also you can create a timer just read database for example every 0.5S. Broadcast to all client when data changed.
$websocket_worker->onWorkerStart = function()
{
    $time_interval = 0.5;
    Timer::add($time_interval, function(){
        // When data changed
        global $connections_array;
        foreach($connections_array as $conn)
        {
            $conn->send('{"type":"message","content":"data changed"}');
        }
    });
};

Worker::runAll();
```

Run with `php websocket_server.php` start for debug

Run with `php websocket_server.php start -d` for daemon

Run with `php websocket_server.php stop` for stop

Run with `php websocket_server.php status` see status